# displaying labels and textfields in java swings

Tags: java, swing

I can't understand why in the following code only the button is being displayed , and why aren't label and textfield displayed.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Invent extends JFrame
{
    public Invent(){
        JFrame c=new JFrame("trying");
        JLabel label1;
        JTextField txtfld1;
        JButton buttoncomp;  

        label1=new JLabel("Enter the path");
        txtfld1=new JTextField();
        buttoncomp=new JButton("Update");
        c.add(label1);
        c.add(txtfld1);
        c.add(buttoncomp);
        c. pack();
        c.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new Invent();                                                          
    }
}
```

Kindly help ...

Comment: BTW, it is _really_ weird how you create a `new JFrame` in the constructor of a class that `extends JFrame`...

Answer (score 5):

The default layout of a JFrame's content pane is BorderLayout. You're adding all of your components to the BorderLayout.CENTER location (by calling the single-argument add() function), which means that only the last component is added.

Either use a different layout manager, or add the components to different locations in the BorderLayout.

More info about BorderLayout can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html).

Btw, your title has nothing to do with your actual question: the difference between a JFrame and a content pane is that a JFrame **contains** a content pane. The JFrame class **passes** calls like setLayout() and add() to its content pane.

Answer (score -1):

It works incorrect(for you but java does what you say :) )

cause you add (these)three components to JFrame **in row**(the next remove the last)

you must work as follows:

```
   label1.add(txtfld1);
   label1.add(buttoncomp);

   c.add(label1);
   c.pack();
   c.setVisible(true);
```

And something other...

- You had made a new JFrame you dont need to extend it(in you class).
- It's not good to add label(without panel) in HeavyWeight Component like JFrame you **may** have problems with Listeners(mouse,action,whatever...)

Let me know if that works for you...